# LINQ from objects Left Join

Tags: entity-framework, linq, left-join, entity-framework-core

I have a linq query that works fine when I join two tables, but when I include another table, it does not return data.  Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

First Linq returns data:

```
var q = (from c in _context.Complaint
        join cl in _context.Checklist on c.COMP_ID equals cl.COMP_ID into clleft
        from cls in clleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
        orderby c.timestamp descending
        select new
         {
          FileNum = c.FileNum
         }).AsQueryable().Distinct();

         return q;
```

When I add this table, no data returns

```
var q = (from c in _context.Complaint
        join cl in _context.Checklist on c.COMP_ID equals cl.COMP_ID into clleft
        from cls in clleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join oim in _context.OIM_EMPLOYEE on cls.MonitorEnteredEmpID equals oim.EmpID into oimleft
        from oims in oimleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
        orderby c.timestamp descending
        select new
              {FileNum = c.FileNum
              }).AsQueryable().Distinct();

        return q;
```

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong at the first glance. Could be your ORM problem, are you really using LINQ to SQL (and not EntityFramework for instance)?

Comment: @IvanStoev, you are correct, my model is an entity framework.  Is there a better way to perform left joins, as inner join queries work just fine?

Comment: It should be just fine the way you wrote it (although a better way would be to use navigation properties and forget about joins). Can you verify the generated SQL by observing `q.ToString()`?

Comment: It's best not to join directly, but use navigation properties instead - you will have to declare your relational model with referential constraints (foreign keys).

Comment: I gather you're doing a left join properly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx
So in such case, left joining one more table should not change the result set row count by definition

Comment: @IvanStoev, it has a weird microsoft command in between  SELECT filenum FROM [Complaint] AS [c] LEFT JOIN [Checklist] AS [cl] ON [c].[COMP_ID] = [cl].[COMP_ID]
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilderFactory:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [oim].[EmpID]
FROM [OIM_EMPLOYEE] AS [oim]

Comment: Mate, now I see you are actually using EF Core. There is a huuuge difference between EF6 and Core, mainly that Core currently is totally unreliable and full with bugs in query processing. You are lucky that you don't get exception. Seriously, consider switching to EF6 if you can.